# Promise not resolving in angular jasmine unit test

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

My service looks like this:

```
app.service('foo',function($q){
  this.fn3 = function(){
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    return deferred.promise;
  }
});
```

My spec document is as below:

```
describe('Testing: MainCtrl', function() {
  var $scope = null;
  var ctrl = null;
  var mockfoo;
  var deferred;
  var $q;
  var data = {name: 'test'};
  var createController;

  beforeEach(module('plunker'));

  beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller,_$q_) {
    $scope = $rootScope.$new();
    $q = _$q_;  

    mockfoo = {
      fn3: function(){  }
    };

    deferred = $q.defer();
    spyOn(mockfoo,'fn3').and.returnValue(deferred.promise);

     createController = function() {
      return $controller('MainCtrl', {
        $scope: $scope,
        foo: mockfoo  
      });  
    };

  }));

  it('Should call fn3()', function(){
    ctrl = createController(); 
    deferred.resolve(data);
    $scope.$digest();
    expect(mockfoo.fn3).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect($scope.temp).toBe(data);
  });

});
```

I am not quiet sure why this spec is failing. I am resolving the promise and then calling $digest which means that $scope.temp should get a value.

I have a plnkr for this here:
http://plnkr.co/edit/uzWqTT

Any suggestions anybody ?

Comment: It's not shown how `$scope.temp` is being set. But it looks like from the error it is a promise, not the value from a resolved promise. Make sure you're setting `$scope.temp` inside of `.then()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to [catch the resolved](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24q#testing) value by accessing the value in the `then` function:

```
var resolvedValue;
$scope.temp.then(function(value) { resolvedValue = value; });
expect(resolvedValue).toEqual(data);
```

See [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/4PLyqnX8tgfqLC60WrNr?p=preview).